# Is it a bug? (LuaLaTeX AND [russian](Polyglossia OR Babel) AND Cleveref) => ERROR

Tags: luatex, babel, cleveref, polyglossia

So, with the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt, russian]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historical}]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

  % \tracingall
  % \tracingassigns=5
  % \tracingmacros=2
  % \tracingcommands=2
  % \tracingrestores=1
  % \tracingstats=0
  % \tracingoutput=10
  % \tracinggroups=10
  % \tracingonline0

\begin{document}
123
\end{document}


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

I have the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempa ^^@-\CYRR \cyri \cyrs 
                            \cyru \cyrn \cyro \cyrk 
l.3 \select@language{russian}

? X
```

The word 'Risunok' stands for 'Picture' in Russian. (That's the word you get by stripping "\cir"s from what is in the error message.)

Is it a bug? Any help or suggestions?

(As you can conclude by playing with the code it's because of the exact combination in the title of the question - well, it is like so on my machine with fully updated TeX Live 2014).

Comment: Feel free to replace the fonts with ones of your own - it seems not working anyway.

Comment: I get no error if I use `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` *before* `fontspec` and remove the global `russian` option.

Comment: Wow! Why did you do that rearrangement? Just the blind hope?

Comment: `babel` should always go before `fontspec` (there was a question about this yesterday) and I never put the language as a global option. `;-)` However, this probably doesn't solve the issue, because the problem is in the `russian` option to `cleveref` that makes several definitions using `\cyr?` and `\CYR?` commands.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Not really: here the problem is mainly `cleveref`

Comment: @egreg Is it important that the error is about exactly "\cyrs"?

Comment: Hmmm, the OP cannot mark the post as duplicate?